# Fixed amount contactless kiosk type possible?

Tags: square, square-connect

Hi my client is a charity.

They would like to apply a fixed amount to a app/webapp where people can just tap and walk away donating fixed amount without any merchant interaction needed.

Such terminal will probably be fixed to a stand... With a tablet nearby processing it automatically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes! The [Point of Sale API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/point-of-sale-api-overview) offers an [iOS](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/point-of-sale-api-ios), [Android](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/point-of-sale-api-android), and [web-to-Android](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-android) way of making a kiosk app.

For example, if you modify the [HelloCharge example from GitHub](https://github.com/square/point-of-sale-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-hellocharge), you can fix the payment amount and method to whatever you desire.

---

Here's the un-modified HelloCharge app taking a $1 payment.

[image: example of a $1 transaction via Point of Sale API on Android]

Comment: Thanks. Definitely need to change providers then :-)

Comment: @AbdulHasan None of the other providers I've looked at even offer this, did you find a solution?

Comment: @unknowndomain Havent I tested the solution above briefly. But havent worked on it since to integrate to my app.